# OpenVPN работает, но не открываются сайты блокированные РКН

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Есть сервер в Германии на Amazon Lightsail, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, на нём поднят OpenVPN по этой инструкции.

https://habr.com/ru/post/233971/

Далее настроены Iptables по примеру отсюда

https://interface31.ru/tech_it/2019/10/nastroyka-openvpn-servera-dlya-dostupa-v-internet.html

В Openvpn на сервере dns гугла прописаны.
Подключаюсь с клиента win10. Всё подключается, соединяется, 2ip показывает Ip из openvpn и локация Германия, сайты открываются. [www.dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com) показывает тоже германию.

НО, не открываются сайты, заблокированные роскомнадзором: rutracker, linkedin и т.д. Показывает не заглушку ркн, а просто страница не найдена.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Чтобы не проделывать вручную кучу шагов по установке и настройке OpenVPN, то есть различные автоустановщики, например: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Answer (score 2):

Дело было в dns leak
Добавил в конфиг сервера

```
push "block-outside-dns"
```

Итог: сайты открываются, полная проверка на [www.dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com) показывает что утечек нет

Comment: Круто, что сами разобрались, и другим подсказали!